# p5.js createColorPicker() undefined error

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am creating a drawing app for a University project and while I created the html where this should go and used the documentation from [p5.js website](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createColorPicker), whenever I try to run this, I would get the undefined error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: createColorPicker is not defined"

Usually, the error occurs on the line that I am calling the createColorPicker() function, in this instance it is on my sketch file on line 25. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to understand why am I getting the undefined error, I have all the p5 libraries in my html. Please see the below code:

index file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="lib/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/p5.dom.js"></script>

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>

    <!-- add extra scripts below -->
    <script src="toolbox.js"></script>
    <script src="colourPalette.js"></script>
    <script src="helperFunctions.js"></script>

    <script src="freehandTool.js"></script>
    <script src="lineToTool.js"></script>
    <script src="sprayCanTool.js"></script>
    <script src="mirrorDrawTool.js"></script>
    <script src="circleTool.js"></script>
    <script src="stampTool.js"></script>
    <script src="eraserTool.js"></script>
    <script src="editableShapes.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box header">My Drawing App

        <button id="clearButton">Clear</button>
        <button id="saveImageButton">Save Image</button>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="sidebar"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div class="box colourPalette"></div>
      <div class="box colorPicker"><p>Color Picker</p></div>
      <div class="box options" id="option1"></div>
      <div class="box options2" id="optionsSize"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

sketch.js file:

```
//global variables that will store the toolbox colour palette
//amnd the helper functions
var toolbox = null;
var colourP = null;
var helpers = null;
var circleTool = null;
var circleImg;
var stampTool;
var colorPicker;
//needed to control the fill/unfill button of circleTool
var circleButtonState; 
var c;

function preload() {
    circleImg = loadImage("./assets/amongus.png");
    stampTool = new StampTool();
    stampTool.image = loadImage("./assets/amongus.png");
}

function setup() {
    //create a canvas to fill the content div from index.html
    canvasContainer = select('#content');
    c = createCanvas(canvasContainer.size().width, canvasContainer.size().height);
    c.parent("content");
    colorPicker = createColorPicker('deeppink');
    colorPicker.parent('colorPicker');
    //create helper functions and the colour palette
    helpers = new HelperFunctions();
    colourP = new ColourPalette();
    circleTool = new CircleTool();
    circleButtonState = false;
    //create a toolbox for storing the tools
    toolbox = new Toolbox();

    //add the tools to the toolbox.
    toolbox.addTool(new FreehandTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new LineToTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new SprayCanTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new mirrorDrawTool());
    toolbox.addTool(circleTool);
    toolbox.addTool(stampTool);
    toolbox.addTool(new EraserTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new EditableShapes());
    background(255);

}

function draw() {
    //call the draw function from the selected tool.
    //hasOwnProperty is a javascript function that tests
    //if an object contains a particular method or property
    //if there isn't a draw method the app will alert the user
    if (toolbox.selectedTool.hasOwnProperty("draw")) {
        toolbox.selectedTool.draw();
    } else {
        alert("it doesn't look like your tool has a draw method!");
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: At first glance you're doing the right thing calling `createColorPicker` in `setup`. It's not super simple to replicate your setup/issue. One wild guess I have is the function isn't available yet. You can try swapping the `p5.dom.js` import the `p5.min.js` and hope they load in that order or trigger the function once the sketch is fully loaded (with all libraries ready).

Comment: This looks OK at a glance. Please create a runnable [mcve]. Are all of those missing scripts and images necessary to replicate the problem? If it's a failing import, you should be able to repro this fully with a few-line index.html that has the scripts in the same order you're loading them in the larger project, plus a few-line sketch.js with the failing call in `setup()`, with all the extra information removed. Please verify that it is runnable and fails for the same reason the larger script does, and share that, along with your p5 version numbers. Thanks.

Comment: `setup()` should not run until all scripts are loaded--scripts load top to bottom, so if your `sketch.js` is below the p5 imports, which it is, there's no possible way for code in `sketch.js` (like `setup()`) to be running before imports above it have resolved. Even if scripts were out of order, p5 delays looking for and running `setup()` until after the load event, almost certainly.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the same project and faced the same problem. I found the solution by updating the p5.min.js file.

The file attached to the project is very old and does not appear to contain functionality related to this feature.